# Handling SFTP logs in AWS EC2 attached with ELB

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp, amazon-elb

We have one sftp server with sftp logs enabled. ELB is attached to this SFTP server.

If any of SFTP user accessing sftp server via ELB, in sftp logs, we are getting ELB's internal IPs, Instead of showing Actual IP or Public IP of user. We need SFTP user's actual IP in SFTP logs instead of ELB internal IPs.

How to handle this in better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different cloud / service providers use different HTTP headers to pass real user IPs across the infrastructure. Examples include: `X-Forwarded-For`,`X-Real-Ip`, even `X-Client-Ip` and so on.

Please see this documentation for AWS - they are using the XFF header (X-Forwarded-For):
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/log-client-ip-load-balancer-apache/